# How know apps that have permission to access internet

Tags: android, permissions

I make an app that need to know which application in device have permission to access to internet . 
Anyone can help me?
( I searched my question but I found nothing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check it this way

```
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
    for (int i=0; i < appinstall.size(); i++)
    {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = appinstall.get(i);
        PermissionInfo[] permissions = packageInfo.permissions; 
        // permissions  The array of all the permissions



    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: thank you , but this answer is to know my app have permission or not . I need to know other apps permission

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution (thanx for Kushal answer)
This is a function that give list of apps that have permission of access to internet

```
private List<PackageInfo> getAppsWithInternetPermission(){
    List<PackageInfo> appsThatHaveInternetPermissin = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    for (int i=0; i < appinstall.size(); i++)
    {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = appinstall.get(i);
        permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions; 

        try{

            for (String permissinName : permissions) {
                if(permissinName.equals("android.permission.INTERNET")){
                    appsThatHaveInternetPermissin.add(packageInfo);
                }
            }

        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            Log.i("catch messege", e + "");
        }
    }

    return appsThatHaveInternetPermissin;
}
```